# List all folders with pictures

Tags: android

I want to know if it is possible to get all folders with pictures on smartphone.
How can I get those folders?

I don't want only the pictures on this folder (where are the photos taken with the camera):

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+ Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query all the files within your storage recursively using

file.listfile();

and then check their extensions with

```
 public static String getExtension(File f) {
    String ext = null;
    String s = f.getName();
    int i = s.lastIndexOf('.');

    if (i > 0 && i < s.length() - 1) {
        ext = s.substring(i + 1).toLowerCase();
    }
    return ext;
}
```

This way you can get all the pictures in your storage. Then you can use any string format method or file.getParent to get their folder.

Answer (score 0):

you need 2 list. one for storing folders and one for files. and you must dynamically add files and folders to this list. in each directory you must search for all files and folders. if file that you searched is file then you add it to file list else you add it to the folders list. then again you do this for all folders in list of folders.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use Linux Power. I create simple example.

```
InputStream is = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream out = null;
String[] files = null;
try {
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String[] command = new String[]{"ls", "-R", path, "| grep .png" };
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    builder.redirectErrorStream();
    builder.directory(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    Process process = builder.start();

    is = process.getInputStream();
    out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int count = 0; 
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while((count = is.read(buffer)) > 0){
        out.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    out.flush();
    files = new String(out.toByteArray()).split("\n");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally{
    if(is != null){
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(out != null){
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

List<String> imageFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String file : files){
    if(file.endsWith(".png") || file.endsWith(".jpeg") || file.endsWith(".jpg") || file.endsWith(".gif")){
        imageFiles.add(file);
    }
}
```